# play 2 different package for views

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to move my views out of the default views package into mynewpackage.view.xyz. It was not a problem with the controllers.

It seems like they are not compiled at all.

Play 2.0 doc says:

> ... Note that in Play 2.0, the controllers, models and views package name conventions are now just that and can be changed if needed (such as prefixing everything with com.yourcompany). ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: GOT IT! First I had to create a valid controller class:

return ok("Test");

Then reload the page. Before reloading finished the view was automatically compiled.

Now I could change back the code to

return ok(mynewpackage.view.xyz.index.render("Test"));

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Create new package in `/app` let's call it `com.mycompany.views`
2. Create new view in it: `myView.scala.html`
3. Return it in action: `return ok(com.mycompany.views.html.myView.render());`

As can you see there's important `html` part between package name and view name, to get views compiled without reloading the page start Play with command: `play ~run`

Answer (score 0):

1) clone views to your new package. 
2) clean and compile. 
3) change import references